# Google Scripts onEdit "reacts" two times in a row

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, edit

I'm basically trying to keep a blank row on top of a sheet I use for records, the issue here is every time I edit (and I'm making sure I only do it *once*) one among A5 to J5, it feels like the script runs twice and two rows get added.
Plus, newly added rows don't inherit the style and formulas, but I feel like I can fix that.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Transactions');
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editedColumn = e.range.getColumn();

  if (editedRow === 5 && editedColumn >= 1 && editedColumn <= 10) {
    sheet.insertRowBefore(5);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you create an installable trigger for this onEdit function? If so you're getting two triggers one is simple and one is installable.

Answer (score 1):

This should be triggered on any edit of sheet named Transactions and on any column between 1 and 10

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Transactions" && e.range.rowStart == 5 && e.range.columnStart < 11) {
    sheet.insertRowBefore(5);
  }
}
```

Check executions to see if your getting multiple triggers.  Your script could fire on edits to other sheets/tabs.